# svn merge xml based file

Tags: svn, svn-merge

We are facing a problem in the code merge and un-merge, Please advice : Problem statement is below:

We are using SVN as SCM, We have a trunk, from trunk we have created the a Branch B1 for the development,

We have multiple projects going on the same branch, different developer is working on different project on the same branch.

Lets say we have 3 projects going on same branch P1 , P2 , P3 and P4. Changes for the all projects done in the same branch.

Now lets assume project P3 development is completed, now we have to move this code changes to production , we need  to merge the code changes done for the P3 project to the trunk.

**Code is a XML based file.**

I tried SVN cherry picking, but it is not working when same file is modified for more than 1 projects (as this is XML)

Please suggest how can we do the code merge in this case. 
Do we have any other tool available in  the market to achieve this.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Bhanu Prakash

Answer (score 0):

It is not the way svn is supposed to be used, and for a reason. Using a better workflow (one branch per project) should prevent this kind of issues in the future.

At the present point, if you are lucky, cherry picking can work. That is, if the lines modified by the various projects do not overlap.

If cherry picking fails, I don't see a "good" solution. Depending on the project, some options:

- Go over the code manually.
- Or cleanup the branch and merge it all, with other projects unfinished. After that, branch again for the trunk, once per project, so they can be finished with a better workflow.